# May I put full length movies or TV shows here?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, questions, reference

When there is an question or answer is it ok to put a link to the movie if available on the internet as a side note?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Why is the side note needed?

We support embedding of video (mostly YouTube) but questions or answers rarely require the **whole movie**.

Indeed, since the video can't be indexed by search engines you would be required to explain  the answer in words anyway...so the video is often superfluous.

The other issue is copyright infringement...most movies are not "available on the internet"...unless obtained by, shall we say, dubious sources.

While SE may not be *strictly* liable, I'm pretty sure that's not an area they'd like to wade into too deeply.

Basically, **unless the whole movie is required** to ask or answer (and I can't think of any instance where this would be the case)... I'd say

## NO.